# ERROR:(Input string was not in a correct format).multiple deletions in gridview getting

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)grow.FindControl("chk1");
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    int empid =int.Parse((grow.Cells[0]).Text);
                    deleterecord(empid);
                }
            }
            Bind();
        }



        protected static void deleterecord(int empid)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=desktop-tvrrh2v;Initial Catalog=FROMSQL;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from grrid where id=@id", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",empid);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Some explanation would help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is failing here:

```
int empid =int.Parse((grow.Cells[0]).Text);
```

because `(grow.Cells[0]).Text` cannot be parsed as int.
I suggest you change that code like this:

```
int empid;

if (int.TryParse((grow.Cells[0]).Text, out empid)) {
    // Valid input, do something with it.
    deleterecord(empid);
} else {
    // Not a number, do something else with it.
    //throw error, try to fix state
}
```

It is highly recommended to always use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) when you are convert types.